# disqus-- change 'comment' word

Tags: profiling, cpu-word, comments, disqus

how i can change 'comment' word to 'review' from total number of comment [ 6 comment ] -> [ 6 review ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this on the Disqus website, in "Settings" > "Appearance" (`http://your-site-slug.disqus.com/admin/settings/appearance/`).

[image: Settings - Appearance]

Almost at the bottom of that page, you have the "Comment count link" setting, where you can change the text for zero, one or more comments.
[image: Comment count link]

Comment: appearance section has been removed by disqus now, is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can temporarily disable "Disqus 2012", change the settings and then re-enable 2012

Comment: Just to clarify, this is now available in 'Disqus 2012', but under 'Settings'.

Answer (score 0):

This is updated GUI you can find it "Settings" > "General" and if you need to remove 'comment' word  you can't so you have to add something like this

```
0 <span></span>
```

[image]

Comment: any details .. or steps?

Comment: I did as you mentioned and  nothing is changed!
However I've contacted the support team, and they said just create multiple accounts for each language, and let's face it, in this way it's so much logical to handle each language by different team.