# Disqus Comment System [Wordpress] - Change the word "Comment"

Tags: disqus, appearance

i have installed Disqus comment system on one of my wordpress blogs, but i want the comment numbers to show as `0` instead of `0 Comments` or `12` instead of `12 Comments`. Previously there used to be an Appearance section in Disqus admin that used to have an option to change this output as was suggested in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573684/disqus-change-comment-word). But seems like the `Appearance` section has been taken off by Disqus. Is there any other way to achieve this (without messing with the plugin code, ofcourse.) ??

UPDATE:

Well, looked into the plugin source as well but no use, seems like they are updating it using javascript. After enabling `Reactions` now it returns `0 comments and 0 Reactions`.

UPDATE#2:

okie so i at last found where it is coming from ... the plugin basically includes a `count.js` files from `yoursite.disqus.com\count.js?some wierd parameters`, and the js file looks something like this:

```
var DISQUSWIDGETS;

if (typeof DISQUSWIDGETS != 'undefined') {
    DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount({"showReactions": true, "text": {"and": "and", "reactions": {"zero": "0 Reactions", "multiple": "{num} Reactions", "one": "1 Reaction"}, "comments": {"zero": "0 Comments", "multiple": "{num} Comments", "one": "1 Comment"}}, "counts": [{"reactions": 0, "uid": 1, "comments": 0}, {"reactions": 0, "uid": 0, "comments": 0}, {"reactions": 0, "uid": 3, "comments": 0}, {"reactions": 0, "uid": 2, "comments": 0}, {"reactions": 0, "uid": 4, "comments": 0}]});
}
```

the worst part is we can't even change the code in the `js` file as it is hosted on `disqus` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hide it via JavaScript.

Something along these lines:

```
node = document.getElementsByClassName("dsq-comment-count")[0].childNodes[0]
node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace("Comments", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can "hack" the code of Disqus. I'll try to explain what I did step-by-step:

1. Get the newest file of the main disqus function. It should be something similar to this:
   `http://disqus.com/forums/(your-site-id)/count.js`
2. Copy that script somewhere, you can "beautify it" to make it more readable. Than find and change the `displayCount` function to whatever you want to like this:

   ```
   c.displayCount = function (a)
   {
     for (var b, c, e, g, f = 0; f < a.counts.length; f++)
     if (b = a.counts[f], c = h[b.uid]) e = b.comments === 0 ? "0 drivels" : b.comments == 1 ? "1 drivel" : "{num} drivels",
     g = e.replace("{num}", b.comments),
     a.showReactions && (e = b.reactions === 0 ? a.text.reactions.zero : b.reactions == 1 ? a.text.reactions.one : a.text.reactions.multiple, e !== "" && (g += " " + a.text.and + " " + e.replace("{num}", b.reactions))),
     c.element.innerHTML = g
   };
   ```

   (note the drivels ;)
3. Save (upload) the whole file somewhere on your server and remember the path
4. Use Wordpress administration to edit the Disqus plugin - file `disqus-comment-system/disqus.php` and find line that contains concatenated url withthe word `count.js`. It is in about 3/4 of the file. As of now the line looks like this but it might change in the future:

   ```
   s.src = '//' + '<?php echo DISQUS_DOMAIN; ?>/forums/' + disqus_shortname + '/count.js';
   ```
5. Make this link point to your newly-uploaded file like this (I used relative URL):

   ```
   s.src = '/wp-include/custom/disqus-count.js';
   ```
6. Save it and profit! It took me more than an hour to figure this out so I hope this actually helps someone (I needed to translate these messages into my native language). A great benefit of this approach is the fact that if your language uses different word forms for different numbers (other than 0, 1 and more), you can script it in.

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624#customizing-link-text

1. Go to http://YOUR-SITE.disqus.com/admin/settings/?p=general
2. Edit Comment Count Link section as you need.
3. That's all!